# gsub and sub in R not working

Tags: r, stringr

I have date in characters

```
aa <- '2/3/2015'
qq <- gsub('\\d+\\/\\d+\\/\\d+{4}', '', aa)
```

but qq returns`""`

what am I doing wrong? I also tried with sub() function but both of them results in `""`.

I am expecting result to be `'2/3/2015'` not `""`

Comment: You are actually ASKING to be replaced to `""` (gsub's second argument). There's nothing wrong with your code as far as I can see.

Comment: perhaps you are looking for `qq <- grep('\\d+\\/\\d+\\/\\d+{4}', aa,value = TRUE )`. Try that.

Comment: @RicardoFernandesCampos Sorry I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct function that can be used by `OP` is `grep`.

```
aa <- '2/3/2015'
qq <- grep('\\d+\\/\\d+\\/\\d+{4}', aa,value = TRUE )
qq
#[1] "2/3/2015"

#Same thing can be achieved by gsub or sub as:
qq <- gsub('(\\d+\\/\\d+\\/\\d+{4})', '\\1', aa )
qq
#[1] "2/3/2015"

#OR even you can try
qq <- gsub('(\\d+\\/\\d+\\/\\d+{4})', 'Date: \\1', aa )
qq
#[1] "Date: 2/3/2015"

#The real use of gsub/sub is when one need partial string as:
qq <- gsub('\\d+\\/\\d+\\/(\\d+{4})', 'Year: \\1', aa )
qq
#[1] "Year: 2015"
```